# Open-Close Principle Example

Tags: java, open-closed-principle

I want to apply the Open-close principle on this following example by re-writing this code.

```
class MyQueue<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Queue<E> {
   int front=0, back=0;
   MyQueue() { }
   …
   void put(E e) { add(back++, e); ...}
   E get () { E elem = get(front++); …}
}
```

What design pattern would the solution most closely match, and why? Explain why it’s a better match than the next best match.

I am having trouble thinking of what features this class would extend. It already has the getter and setter. Without knowing what type of extensions can be applied, I am not sure how to rewrite this code.

**What I know:** OCP is open for extension-closed to modification. Thus, a general approach is to figure out how to abstract it. So my initial thought was to make this an abstract class with abstract methods. Then, every class that would extend `MyQueue()` would be able to implement the getter and setter methods however it wanted. And, if I do this, then I'd assume that this closely matches the adaptor pattern.

Please correct any mis-understandings I have with my understanding.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted... I followed the guidelines of asking a question. Can someone clarify? It doesn't help to just be down-voted without knowing why.

Comment: Most likely, it was downvoted for looking like homework and requesting opinions.

Comment: Question is quite nice. Maybe close to homework but still its more like understanding of `OCP` in practice. This isn't obvious all the time.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective this is an example of making `Queue` based on `ArrayList` implementation. First of all I will try to expose only `Queue` interface method. All methods that will be inherited from `ArrayList` should be somehow hidden.

Thing is, we know that in Java you can't hide public method during inheritance. 
Then, only approach you can take is to override them and throw `UnsupportedOperationException` or sth like this.

You need to make sure you will implement correctly `Queue` interface based on `ArrayList` inside.
You should implement correctly `add`, `offer`, `remove`, `pool`, `element`, `peek`. Other methods originating from `ArrayList` should throw some exception.

This is my opinion on this subject.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are suggesting that I make this "MyQueue()" class as a interface, adding all the functions that ArrayList has such as add, offer, remove, etc. then every concrete class can implement their own versions of this getters/setters/etc. Correct?

Comment: In which case, am I correct to assume that it follows the adaptor pattern?

Comment: Answering on first comment. I am suggesting to look at `MyQueue` class as a queue.
Second comment answer: More or less it is adaptor. You are trying to adapt `ArrayList` to `Queue`. What I was trying to show there is please try use `ArrayList` as the mechanism of your `Queue`. Going back to usage you should assign `MyQueue` instance to `Queue` interface.
Like: `Queue yourQueue = new MyQueue()`.